# How to Delete Selected row from a datagrid in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

pls help me.. i already done try to call my database to datagrid, but now i can't find a way to delete my data from selected row at datagrid

my datagrid from here

```
Private Sub cmdTampil_Click()
AdoCupu.ConnectionString = Buka
AdoCupu.RecordSource = "Select * from vJadwalRehab Where jadwalrehab between '" & Format(dtDari, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "' and '" & Format(dtpSampai, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "'"
AdoCupu.Refresh
Set dgData.DataSource = AdoCupu
End Sub
```

i tried these methods on 'delete button' but still won't work

```
Private Sub cmdHapus_Click()

1.method 'dgData.(1).index
    dgData.rows.RemoveAt (i)
'dgData.Delete

2.method      ' Dim index As Integer
       ' index = dgData.CurrentCell.RowIndex

3.method   ' delete the selected row
       ' dgData.rows.RemoveAt (index)
        'If Not dgData.CurrentRow.IsNewRow Then
        'dgData.rows.Remove (dgData.CurrentRow)
    'End If
End Sub
```

i tried those 3 method but didn't work..

Comment: Could you tell us which datagrid you are using?  The Data Bound Grid Control?  The DataGrid Control?  The FlexGrid Control?  The Grid Control?

Comment: it's 'DataGrid' only on property name, anyway i fixed it, but thank you for reply my post..

Answer (score 0):

i found it! just delete index number'primary key' from table n row of data gone..

```
CONN.BeginTrans
CONN.Execute "delete jadwalRehab where id='" & txtID & "'"
CONN.CommitTrans
ShowData
MsgBox "Data Jadwal Berhasil Dihapus!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fill in your grid, the easy way of deleting records is through the Adodc control:

```
Private Sub cmdHapus_Click()
   Dim bm As Variant

   For Each bm In dgData.SelBookmarks
      AdoCupu.Recordset.Bookmark = bm
      AdoCupu.Recordset.Delete
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for rep, but i can't use 'for each' on vb6.0

Comment: Why not?  I guess the main point is the contents of the loop.  Set the Bookmark and call Delete.  This is much easier than creating a transaction and throwing an SQL statement at the DB and then refilling the entire grid.